# Is it suitable to pass a click event to a submit handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a `<form>` that I want to submit by clicking an `<a>` because a library I use builds buttons using `<a>` tags rather than `<button>` or `<input type='submit'>`.

The form's `onsubmit` attribute is set by PHP via Laravel.

I have a script to handle the clicks on the `<a>`, which works well for the page I'm building.  The submit handler for my page doesn't currently utilize the event.  But I want to make this generic.  Therein lies the question:

**Is it ok to send the "click" event generated by an anchor to a form submit handler, or does it need a "form submit" event?**

Here is my code:

```
<form method="POST" action="somewhere" onsubmit="return form_sub()" id="myForm">...</form>

<a id='saveButton' href='#'>Save</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#saveButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $f = $('#myForm');
        if ($f.prop('onsubmit')) {
            if ($f.prop('onsubmit')(e)) { // <-- there, that event, passed to a handler that might expect a different "type" of event?
                $f.submit();
            }
        } else {
            $f.submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm also willing to entertain ideas that I've missed something and there's an easier way do this - some way to submit the form which includes/doesn't include a call to the submit handler based on whether or not the handler exists, which may also extend to handlers installed via `.addEventListener`.  I realize that `$(form).submit()` calls event handlers installed by `$(form).submit(handler)` but that is not the case for this question, and I want this code to cover handlers installed both ways.

Comment: not all people execute js... also have you tried $("#myform")[0].submit(); wich calls the js function?

Comment: Certainly not appropriate for accessibility. Why can't you just copy css for `<a>` to an `input`?

Comment: @Jonasw [The form's onsubmit event handler...is not guaranteed to be invoked by HTML user agents.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)

Comment: The function called by `$f.prop('onsubmit')(e)` will be the invisible anonymous function put in place by `onsubmit="return form_sub()"`. If you want `e` (good or bad) to be usable in `form_sub()`, then you would need to write something like `onsubmit="return form_sub.apply(null, arguments)"` or attach your onsubmit handler in js not HTML.

Comment: That's a good point @Roamer-1888 and also illustrates that functions set via `onsubmit="func"`don't typically handle `e`

Comment: Yes indeed, and this complication pushes you even further in the direction advocated by @charlietfl.

Answer (score 1):

You could put an off screen `input type="submit"` or `button type="submit"` and trigger click on that so that user can still submit by keyboard and for screen readers/accessibility

```js
function form_sub() {
  alert('Submiting');
  return false;
}
$(function() {
  $('#saveButton').click(function() {
    $('#submit-btn').click();
  })
})
```

```css
#submit-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
  left: -999em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="somewhere" onsubmit="return form_sub()" id="myForm">

  <a id='saveButton' href='#'>Save</a>
  <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

Ideally however it should be relatively easy to copy your library button styles to an `input`

Comment: Thanks charlie, after reading your comment I tried styling a `<button>` instead of an `<a>` and the results worked well, and of course that takes care of the submit event handler part.  I would still like to know if the events are compatible.

Comment: To be honest any workarounds are just hacks ... styling proper element is best

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#saveButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myForm").submit()
});
```